# TableView Cell not loading View Controller until Different TableView Cell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, pushviewcontroller

I've searched around and haven't truly found why this is happening. Basically, I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yupIw9FXUso by Jared Davison on creating Table View Cells to Multiple View controllers. In his example, everything works perfectly, but for some reason when you click on a table view cell in my code the cell is highlighted in grey. Then, when the user clicks on a separate table view cell the view controller that should have been loaded by the first table view cell is loaded. If the user then clicks back on the original table view cell the page that should have been loaded by the second table view cell is loaded. In summary, all of the view controllers are loaded a "click" behind.

Here is the code for the table view:

```
//Feed Navigation Functions
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return elements.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75
}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell") as! FeedTableViewCell
    cell.txtTitle.text = "The Fight Against \(elements[indexPath.row])"
    cell.issueIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Issue Icons_\(elements[indexPath.row])")
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
```

Update: The array is a simple array of strings for example `[One, Two, Three]` there are 6 strings in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select a cell then select another one the method `didDeselectRow` is called so the Vc is pushed you actually want to implement `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    // this to deSelect it after push
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

}
```

This method fired when a cell is selected

> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath

This method fired when a cell is deSelected

> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath

Comment: Your code is the exact same as mine. I don’t understand what you think I should change?

Comment: change this didDeselectRowAt  to this didSelectRowAt  ,,, look carefully to method name

Comment: I just realized that. It feels like a total facepalm moment when you totally miss the most important part. A quick add on to this question: now when I return from the view controller using a back button the cell is still highlighted is there a way to change that?

Comment: This is the correct response. Should use `didSelectRowAt` not `didDeselectRowAt` as you currently use.

Answer (score 1):

Issue: `click on a table view cell in my code the cell is highlighted in grey` 
This is due to the `selectionStyle`, which you can read about [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623221-selectionstyle). If you don't want the cell highlighted, you can set `cell.selectionStyle = .none`.

Edit: As indicated in other correct response - issue was with incorrect/typo in method - we should use `didSelectRowAt` not `didDeselectRowAt`.

Comment: I changed it to use only one array, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you're populating the array of data?

Comment: I did update the question. Hope that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the tableView's delegate method `didSelectRow` instead of `didDeselectRow` I think...